# What game are they playing in Elizabeth Moody’s ‘The Temptation’?

Tags: meaning, poetry, elizabeth-moody

Here’s an extract from ‘The Temptation; or, Satan in the Country’ by [Elizabeth Moody](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elizabeth_Moody):

> The verdant table Satan spy’d,
>   And took his seat by Lydia’s side;
>   Soon as he hovers o’er her hand,
>   Lydia finds aces at command;
>   From one *known* shuffle amply pours
>   *Sans prendre* games and matadores.
>   Then perching next on Cosmo’s sword,
>   Two fish were pilfer’d from the board.
>
> <sub>Elizabeth Moody (1798). [*Poetic Trifles*, p. 152–3](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=hLVYAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA152). London: Baldwin.</sub>

What game are they playing? What are “*sans prendre* games”, “matadores”, and “fish”? Why is the shuffle “*known*”? What is the significance, if any, of Cosmo’s sword?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Quadrille](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrille_(card_game)), as named in the last line of the poem, is the game. ([This web page](https://www.parlettgames.uk/histocs/quadrill.html) has lots of details and further references.)
I don't know exactly what "known shuffle" means here.  "Sword" seems to mean "spadille", the ace of spades.  I assume Cosmo is the name of one of the players.

Check out, eg, *A Brief and Necessary Supplement to All Former Treatises on Quadrille: Consisting of Hints, Questions, Explanations, References, Suppositions, &c. for the Benefit of the Unlearned* by "No Adept", of 
1764. (See this [online copy](https://play.google.com/books/reader?id=TyPpAOzIrRIC&hl=en&pg=GBS.PA3).)
An excerpt (with modernized capitalization) from page 3:

> Wherefore, without further introduction, as the difference between a *Sans prendre* and a *Vole*, seems not sufficiently attended to by young players, I shall begin with the following illustration of it.
>
> Suppose, for instance, two fish on the board, and eight remaining in the pool, a *Sans prendre* without matadores is one fish better than a *vole* without matadores : and with matadores, it is two fish better than a vole with matadores.  Without matadores it is a matadore better than a vole with matadores  and with matadores two fish and a half better than a *vole* without matadores.

I can almost imagine Moody writing with "No Adept's" handbook open in front of her.